# htacces rewrite not catching underscores

Tags: .htaccess

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-]+) load.php?p=$2
```

the problem is underscores (_) are not redirected.

```
this works: my-page-title

not working: my_page_title
```

any help?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add an underscore inside the square brackets:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([a-zA-Z0-9-z\-_]+) load.php?p=$1
```

Edit: looks like you should also rewrite it like so as you have an extraneous `-z` in there; also, changed the variable to `$1` since you only have 1 group:

```
RewriteRule ^pages/([A-Za-z0-9\-_]+) load.php?p=$1
```